# Tensorflow Tensor reshape and pad with zeros

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Is there a way to reshape a tensor and pad any overflow with zeros? I know ndarray.reshape does this, but as I understand it, converting a Tensor to an ndarray would require flip-flopping between the GPU and CPU.

Tensorflow's reshape() documentation says the TensorShapes need to have the same number of elements, so perhaps the best way would be a pad() and then reshape()?

I'm trying to achieve:

```
a = tf.Tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])
tf.reshape(a, [2,3])
a => [[1, 2, 3],
      [4, 0 ,0]]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tensorflow now offers the pad function which performs padding on a tensor in a number of ways(like opencv2's padding function for arrays):
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad

```
tf.pad(tensor, paddings, mode='CONSTANT', name=None)
```

example from the docs above:

```
# 't' is [[1, 2, 3],
#         [4, 5, 6]]
# 'paddings' is [[1, 1], [2, 2]]
# rank of 't' is 2.
pad(t, paddings, "CONSTANT") ==> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                  [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
                                  [0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0],
                                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

pad(t, paddings, "REFLECT") ==> [[6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4],
                                 [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1],
                                 [6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4],
                                 [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]]

pad(t, paddings, "SYMMETRIC") ==> [[2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2],
                                   [2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2],
                                   [5, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5],
                                   [5, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5]]
```

Comment: what if we want to do something like this `[1,pad,2,pad,3,pad,5,pad,pad,6,pad]` how to use zero padding and masking layer. Plz do you have any idea.

Comment: @DINATAKLIT could something like Pad with PaddingConfig help accomplish what you are looking for? I found this in TF XLA which I am unfamiliar with...does anyone know a way to do this in vanilla TF?
Here is the source(note pic): https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/operation_semantics#pad

Comment: It would have been great to answer the question rather than copy/past the doc

Answer (score 20):

As far as I know, there's no built-in operator that does this ([`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape) will give you an error if the shapes do not match). However, you can achieve the same result with a few different operators:

```
a = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

# Reshape `a` as a vector. -1 means "set this dimension automatically".
a_as_vector = tf.reshape(a, [-1])

# Create another vector containing zeroes to pad `a` to (2 * 3) elements.
zero_padding = tf.zeros([2 * 3] - tf.shape(a_as_vector), dtype=a.dtype)

# Concatenate `a_as_vector` with the padding.
a_padded = tf.concat([a_as_vector, zero_padding], 0)

# Reshape the padded vector to the desired shape.
result = tf.reshape(a_padded, [2, 3])
```

Comment: with the last Tensorflow update, it is now `a_padded = tf.concat([a_as_vector, zero_padding],0)`